# Can't install Tomcat with xampp control panel

Tags: tomcat, windows-7, xampp, windows-7-x64

I successfully installed xampp v3.2.1 following the [JetBrains guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE). In there it has been said that

> Once stopped, we can click the <kbd>X</kbd> next to the server we want to install
>   as a **Windows Service**. For example, we can install Apache as a Windows
>   Service. After clicking the <kbd>X</kbd>, we have to confirm installation by
>   clicking <kbd>Yes</kbd>.

I just did that for `Tomcat` but it's giving a message of

```
[Tomcat]    Service was NOT (un)installed!
```

What to do?

A pic so you can see as well

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out!

I went to

> C:\xampp\tomcat

and clicked the `tomcat_service_uninstall.bat` file. Then return to xampp control panel and tried to install it and shazam!

Answer (score 2):

Late edit but I solved it like this after installing XAMPP 7.4.2.0 on a Windows x64 PC:

- Downloaded and installed `JDK 13.0.2`
- Opened notepad and the files `tomcat_service_install.bat` and `tomcat_service_uninstall.bat` found in the `xampp\tomcat` directory.
- Edit the line (found in both files) `set KeyName=HKEY_Local_Machine\SOFTWARE\Javasoft\Java Development Kit` and changed to `set KeyName=HKEY_Local_Machine\SOFTWARE\Javasoft\JDK`

After that I had no problem installing/uninstalling the Tomcat Service as a Windows Service.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem like you, but i finally can resolve this and it worked
the problem is happend due to, you not installed tomcat as service windows [RESOLVE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvvr3.jpg)

first at all

1. Open your CMD as administrator,
2. browse your tomcat bin files " my files tomcat files like this: C:\xampp\tomcat\bin",
3. On CMD switch to cd C:\xampp\tomcat\bin,
4. then, type "service install",
5. finnaly, you can installed tomcat on xampp.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Tomcat, it is best to install it regardless of any other service. In this case there should be any conflict between servers.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing as you, I did just install the JDK.
1. Download the Java SE Development Kit, please click [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

2. If you use windows 64bit please pick Windows x64.
3. If you use windows 32bit please pick Windows x86.
4. If you use not windows please choose another. After that, please install on your computer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Java Development Kit (JDK) has to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

For xampp 8.2.12 had fixed Tomcat batch files:

**tomcat_service_install.bat**

```
@echo off

if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" goto WinNT

:Win9X
echo Don't be stupid! Win9x don't know Services
goto exit

:WinNT

echo [XAMPP]: Searching JDK HOME with reg query ...
set KeyName=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK

reg query "%KeyName%" /s
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 (
  echo . [XAMPP]: Cannot find current JDK installation!
  echo . [XAMPP]: Cannot set JAVA_HOME. Aborting ...
  goto :END
)

set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
set "CATALINA_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%"

set Cmd=reg query "%KeyName%" /s
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('%Cmd% ^| find "JavaHome"') do set JAVA_HOME=%%j

echo.
echo [XAMPP]: Seems fine!
echo [XAMPP]: Using %JAVA_HOME%
echo.

set JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%

echo [XAMPP]: Using JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%
echo [XAMPP]: Using CATALINA_HOME=%CATALINA_HOME%
echo [XAMPP]: Using JRE_HOME=%JRE_HOME%

echo Installing Tomcat as an Service

cd "%CURRENT_DIR%\bin"

call service.bat install Tomcat8.exe

cd "%CURRENT_DIR%"

goto exit

:END

:exit
```

**tomcat_service_uninstall.bat**

```
@echo off

if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" goto WinNT

:Win9X
echo Don't be stupid! Win9x don't know Services
goto exit

:WinNT

echo [XAMPP]: Searching JDK HOME with reg query ...
set KeyName=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK

reg query "%KeyName%" /s
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 (
  echo . [XAMPP]: Cannot find current JDK installation! 
  echo . [XAMPP]: Cannot set JAVA_HOME. Aborting ...
  goto :END
)

set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
set "CATALINA_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%"

set Cmd=reg query "%KeyName%" /s
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('%Cmd% ^| find "JavaHome"') do set JAVA_HOME=%%j

echo.
echo [XAMPP]: Seems fine!
echo [XAMPP]: Using %JAVA_HOME%
echo.
 
set JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%

echo [XAMPP]: Using JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%
echo [XAMPP]: Using CATALINA_HOME=%CATALINA_HOME%
echo [XAMPP]: Using JRE_HOME=%JRE_HOME%

echo Try to stop Tomcat7 service
net stop Tomcat7
echo Uninstall Tomcat as an Service

cd "%CURRENT_DIR%\bin"

echo In original file triggers Tomcat7
call service.bat remove Tomcat8.exe

cd "%CURRENT_DIR%"

goto exit

:END

:exit
```

Although running these files the service is created, the action of activating the service from the xampp control panel is broken.